# I'm having an issue with querying using the 'whereJsonContains' method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this category page '[https://go2hand.com/laptop-cu-c18](https://stackoverflow.com)'.

- When I filter by the 'Màu sắc' (Colour) attribute, the debug only reaches the line '**select count(*) as aggregate from products where product_category_id in (19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, '18') and status = 'active' and (json_contains(attribute, '"B\u1ea1c"', '$."Color"'))**' even though the result exists in the 'products' table.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRlHC.png)
- With values that don't have accents (Vietnamese), the filtering returns the correct result, and the debug reaches the line '**select * from products where product_category_id in (19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, '18') and status = 'active' and (json_contains(attribute, '"core I5"', '$."CPU"')) order by created_at desc limit 20 offset 0**'.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrMuv.jpg)
- Here is the code I use to filter product attributes.

```
if (isset($params['filter']) && $params['filter'] !== null) {
$attributeArray = $params['filter'];
foreach ($attributeArray as $attribute => $attributeValues) {
if (!empty($attributeValues)) {
foreach ($attributeValues as $attributeValue) {
$jsonConditions[] = ['attribute->'.$attribute, str_replace( '"', '' ,json_encode($attributeValue )) ];
}
}
}

if (!empty($jsonConditions)) {
$items = $items->where(function ($query) use ($jsonConditions) {
foreach ($jsonConditions as $condition) {
$query->whereJsonContains($condition[0], $condition[1]);
}
});
}
}
```

- 

Here is products table : [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PRlvGcLsb-C1yfm6aWG6k-gEWB_28oah/view?usp=sharing](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
                                                                                                            I hope to be of assistance.
```